# Upgrading AFNetwork to support 64 bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i'm upgrading my app to support 64 bit. Within this process i check each dependency i have. I'm using AFNetwork 1.1.0. Does anyone know if it is sufficient to update it to the latest 1.x version (1.3.4)? I don't want to upgrade to 2.x if i don't have to.

Comment: yeah, you can upgrade without any issues. But if you are going to upgrade to 2.x will break your code, since major version upgrade will break the backward compatibility.

Comment: So the 1.3.4 version is optimized for 64 bit ?

Comment: How you are integrating AFNetworking into your project. is it as a static library or using cocoapods?

Comment: I just changed it to use cocoapods. In the past i just included the sources.

Comment: then there can't be a problem. Also make sure to have arm64 is included in valid architectures. Most of the time this is included by default.